# Should I use this very short Python Quicksort implementation?

Tags: python, efficiency, sorting, big-o, implementations

```
def quicksort(N):
    if len(N) < 2:
        return N
    else:
        less = quicksort([number for number in N[1:] if number < N[0]])
        more = quicksort([number for number in N[1:] if number >= N[0]])

    return sum([less, [N[0]], more], [])

print(quicksort([1, 9, 6, 10, 8, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5]))
```

It seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's as technically adequate than other longer variants of implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are aware of Python's built-in `sort` and are simply asking this as a learning exercise. (If you just want to use the 'best' sort, use Python's built-in `sort` function. It is heavily optimised and will be faster than anything you implement in Python.)

The short answer is, your quicksort function has a bug, and if you fix it then it will work as expected. However there are other things to consider.

**The bug**

The code does not work correctly when there are several elements in the array which are equal to `N[0]`. Try `quicksort([1,2,1,1])`.

**Performance**

Although the asymptotic (big-O) complexity is the same as a standard quicksort, the performance of this code will be reduced due to:

- Lots of creation of new lists (Quicksort can be easily designed to not require any memory allocation)
- Scanning through the list twice rather than once

Try timing your implementation versus another one (use the `timeit` module). Make sure to try large input lists.

Also, quicksort algorithms have a worst-case complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>). If you want a worst-case complexity of O(n log n) you should consider Mergesort, which can also be implemented with very short code.

**Clarity**

Why

```
return sum([less, [N[0]], more], [])
```

when you can simply do:

```
return less + [N[0]] + more
```

Note that in either case, this still involves the creation of new lists, so the performance could be further improved, probably at the expense of clarity.

Comment: +1. This *isn't* quicksort, because the main improvement quicksort offers over other logarithmic sort methods (eg mergesort) is the ability to operate in-place.  This is an implementation of the redesign of quicksort usually used in immutable functional languages, but frankly mergesort is better for this purpose in most cases anyway.